# Implied By/Implies Continuity Using the Definition of Continuity

Tags: continuity, definition, epsilon-delta

I have to determine which of some definitions are implied by or imply the continuity of a function in a point.

So I guess I should play with $\varepsilon$ and $\delta$ one time I understood what the definition means (using a graph for example).

#### Definition $\mathcal A$

$$\forall \varepsilon^* \gt 0 \quad \exists \delta^* \gt 0 : \quad if \quad |x-x_0|\lt \varepsilon^* \Rightarrow |f(x)-f(x_0)| \lt \delta^*$$

I tried to draw some graphs and it seems to me that in this case the definition of continuity implies the *definition $\mathcal A$*

Then I tried to prove that the *continuity* implies *$\mathcal A$*

We have *(definition of continuity)*

$$\forall \varepsilon \gt 0 \quad \exists \delta \gt 0 : \quad if \quad |x-x_0|\lt \delta \Rightarrow |f(x)-f(x_0)| \lt \varepsilon$$

Then we have that there exists a $\delta$ for the definition of continuity: I pick this $\delta$ and I use it inside $\mathcal A$

So I choose $\varepsilon^* = \delta $, for that $\delta$ I have that $|x-x_0|\lt\delta$, then $|x-x_0|\lt\varepsilon^*$

Before stating that $\delta$ existed I had to pick an $\varepsilon$, so now I can say there is a $\varepsilon$ such that $|f(x)-f(x_0)| \lt \varepsilon$

I choose $\delta^* = \varepsilon$, then I have

$$\forall \varepsilon^* \gt 0 \quad \exists \delta^* \gt 0 : \quad if \quad |x-x_0|\lt \varepsilon^* \Rightarrow |f(x)-f(x_0)| \lt \delta^*$$

The only thing that makes me unsure that this is a correct proof is the fact that I state $\forall \varepsilon^* = \delta$

But not $\forall \varepsilon^* \gt 0$

Does that make sense?

Comment: definition $\mathcal{A}$ is nonsense, it should read $$\forall \varepsilon^* \gt 0 \quad \exists \delta^* \gt 0 : \quad if \quad |x-x_0|\lt \delta^* \Rightarrow |f(x)-f(x_0)| \lt \varepsilon^*$$

Comment: $\delta > \delta$ and $|x - x_0| < 0$ make no sense.

Comment: @GNUSupporter8964民主女神地下教會 thanks for pointing that out, corrected

Comment: @HennoBrandsma it is not the definition of continuity, that is just a definition for which I have to state if it is implied or imply the definition of continuity

Comment: Then it's **not** equivalent in any to continuity. It implies your function is constant.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma exactly, but does it imply or is implied by continuity, or there aren't any correlations between the two definitions? 
Because by looking at the graph it seemed to me that if a function satisfy the definition of Continuity at a point, then the same function also satisfies the definition $\mathcal A$ at that same point (it could be probable I made some mistakes)

Comment: To answer the other direction, that is false as well. Any discontinuous function which is bounded will satisfy $\cal A$ at every point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that your definition $\cal A$ can be interpreted as following:

Given any $\epsilon^* > 0$, the function $f$ is bounded on $(x_0 - \epsilon^*, x_0 + \epsilon^*)$. If your function is defined on $\Bbb R$, then continuity does imply that, as can be seen by the [Extreme Value Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extreme_value_theorem).

However, it is not true in general. For example, consider $f : (0, 1) \to \Bbb R$ defined by $$f(x) = \dfrac{1}{x}.$$

Consider $x_0 = \dfrac{1}{2}$ and $\epsilon^* = \dfrac{1}{2}$. You should be able to show that no $\delta^* > 0$ exists.

(Note that $$\sup_{|x - x_0| < \frac12} |f(x) - f(x_0)| = \infty$$

in this case.)

Comment: Thanks, didn't think about that case. So the proof I made is without any doubt wrong, this was just one of a few exercises I had on those types of correlation. The problem is that, although of trying to understand the behavior of functions that satisfy the definition and imagine how two definitions could be correlated, I don't know how to prove rigorously when something implies something other regarding continuity. Just to understand what I could have made wrong, was maybe the fact I had to state$\forall \varepsilon^* \gt 0$ instead of $\forall \varepsilon^* = \delta$.

Comment: @Royolh your proof does not work as the definition states that there is same delta for all x and x0 but in continuity that is not the case